# Creating SparkSQL jdbc Federation with Oracle DB table fails with strange error

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create hive table which will point out to oracle db table, but it fails with `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException`

Steps:

Rebuild `spark with hive, hive-thrift` support

Place `oracle-db-connector.jar` in class path

Set up `thrift server`

Connect to it using `beeline`

```
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10100 Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10100
```

Create `hive table:`

```
CREATE TABLE oracle3_connector  
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc  
OPTIONS (
   driver "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
   url "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:AUX3",
   user "ANY",
   dbtable "ANY_TABLE",
   password "ANY_PASS"
);

+---------+--+ | Result  |
+---------+--+
+---------+--+ No rows selected (3.473 seconds)
```

Select data from table

```
select * from oracle3_connector;

Error: org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc does not allow user-specified schemas.; (state=,code=0)
```

**UPD:** The same installation works fine with `postgres`.

Comment: which version of spark you are using ?

Comment: @RamPrasadG spark 2.1.0 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is feature request in apache hive jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1555 
Also it's created long time ago

So if are really need to create hive table backed by oracle table you can use od4h .

Steps:

1. Add od4h libs in hive server classpath and start hive server
2. Connect to this server using beeline
   `!connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000`
3. Check that you have oracle drivers

> 0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> !scan scan complete in 1702ms 13
>   driver classes found Compliant Version Driver Class yes       12.1
>   oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver yes       12.1
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

4. Create table in oracle:

`CREATE TABLE PERSON
(
              NUM NUMBER(*) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
              FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(20)
);`

5. Create table in hive

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE EmployeeDataSimple (
NUM int,
FIRSTNAME string
)
STORED BY 'oracle.hcat.osh.OracleStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
     'oracle.hcat.osh.columns.mapping' = 'NUM,FIRSTNAME')
TBLPROPERTIES (
"mapreduce.jdbc.url" = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:49161/XE",
           "mapreduce.jdbc.username" = "dummy",
"mapreduce.jdbc.password" = "dumb",
"mapreduce.jdbc.input.table.name" = "DUMMY.PERSON"
);`

6. Check that it works as expected:
   `0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> select * from employeedatasimple;
   +-------------------------+-------------------------------+--+
   | employeedatasimple.num  | employeedatasimple.firstname  |
   +-------------------------+-------------------------------+--+
   | 1                       | Andrey                        |
   | 2                       | Dmitry                        |
   | 3                       | Semen                         |
   | 4                       | Vadim                         |
   | 5                       | Pavel                         |
   +-------------------------+-------------------------------+--+
   5 rows selected (1.712 seconds)
   0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000>`

**UPD:** MySQL, Postgres works fine with spark sql

Answer (score 1):

May be your `oracle-db-connector.jar` is not correct.
Below is my test.

[image: screenshot of console showing test]

Comment: i will try to reproduce it with latest version of hive and spark